# Why is my jQuery display function on dropdown not working?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I face an issue. I have written the following code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.show-hide').hide();
        $('.dependent').on('change', function() {
          if ($(this).val() == 'Anders...')
          {
            $('.show-hide').show();
          } else {
            $('.show-hide').hide();
          }
        });
      });
```

But for some reason I can't get it to work properly.
It's on here:
http://go.pardot.com/l/471061/2022-03-29/6fp8dp

I am trying to show the 'Anders...' field based on the value 'Anders...' in the dropdown. But for some reason it either shows up on all answers, it doesn't show up at all OR (my best thus far) it show's on the 'Anders...' value, but doesn't disappear anymore...

Note that I have to work with class selectors due to the form builder limitations.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I picked out a few bits that seemed relevant to the question posted above:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.show-hide').hide();
  $('.dependent').on('change', function(ev) {
    if ($("option:selected", ev.target.selected).text() == 'Anders...') {
      $('.show-hide').show();
    } else {
      $('.show-hide').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="form-field dependent Opleidingen_Amsterdam_Arenaboulevard_61_75 pd-select required required-custom    form-field-secondary dependentFieldSlave dependentField">

  <label class="field-label" for="471061_186248pi_471061_186248">Opleiding *</label>


  <select name="471061_186248pi_471061_186248" id="471061_186248pi_471061_186248" class="select" onchange="">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="2692949">Manager handel (Filiaalmanager)</option>
    <option value="2699837">Anders...</option>
  </select>
</p>
<p class="form-field show-hide Opleidingen_Anders pd-text required required-custom    ">

  <label class="field-label" for="471061_186680pi_471061_186680">Anders *
  <input type="text" name="471061_186680pi_471061_186680" id="471061_186680pi_471061_186680" value="" class="text" size="30" maxlength="65535" onchange="" onfocus="" /></label>

</p>
```

Your `change` event handler is attached to all elements with class `dependent`. The element I found was a `<p>` element with a `<select>` inside. So, whenever the event function is triggered the `this` will point to the `<p>` DOM element. If you want to compare the selected "value" (what you *really* want here is the `.textContent` of the selected option) to the string `"Anders..."` then you will need to do the following:

```
$("option:selected", ev.target.selected).text() == 'Anders...'
```

with `ev.target` being the changed `<select>` element inside the `<p class="... dependent ...">` element.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Yeah, unfortunately this is all I can deliver since it seems to be a particular issue. Unfortunately your fix didn't work... I don't see where script isn't working but it's driving me nuts.